# In two lists, How do I get the values of the second list based on the first list value?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, for-loop, iterator

I have 2 two lists that I zipped. How do I get the value of file1 value_85. The file can be have many of the same names. I need only the first two values of the fileXXX. The first value will have a range 80-90 and the second value will have a range 0-10. there will be values after that, that meet this criteria but I just need the first two.I was thinking of converting the list to a dataframe as showed by the output.

```
the lists:
[file1,value_u,
file1,value_u,
file1,value_85, ##want this value
file1,value_3, ##want this value
file1,value_10,
file1,value_88,
file2,value_u,
file2,value_88, ##want this value
file2,value_2, ##want this value
file2,value_88,
file2,value_0,
file3,value_89, ##want this value
file3,value_2, ##want this value
file3,value_4]

output:
df or list: 
2   file1   value_85
3   file1   value_3
7   file2   value_88
8   file2   value_2
11  file3   value_89
12  file3   value_2
```

Comment: Whats the type of the data?

Comment: Is this a DataFrame or a list? If it’s the former, have you read the Pandas docs? In any case, this is extremely unclear.

Comment: @U10-Forward-ReinstateMonica a zipped list of two appended lists

Comment: @s_col Can’t you just use a for loop, then? I’m not sure I understand what the issue actually is.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Iam not sure how to phrase it clearer. I want to get the value of the second part of the list value_85 based on file1 as shown in my output.

Comment: @s_col _Iam not sure how to phrase it clearer._ Please try? _value of the second part of the list value-85_ What list value_85? What’s file1? As far as I can tell you haven’t mentioned those a single time before, so how are we supposed to know what they are?

Comment: Also you say _only the first two values_, _I just need the first two_, but your output contains 6 rows, 3 from each range?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first filter rows with numbers in last character by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and `\d$` - `$` is end of string with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
print (df)
        A         B
0   file1   value_u
1   file1   value_u
2   file1  value_85
3   file1   value_3
4   file1  value_10
5   file1  value_88
6   file2   value_u
7   file2  value_88
8   file2   value_2
9   file2  value_88
10  file2   value_0
11  file3  value_89
12  file3   value_2
13  file3   value_4


df = df[df['B'].str.contains('\d$')].groupby('A').head(2)
print (df)
        A         B
2   file1  value_85
3   file1   value_3
7   file2  value_88
8   file2   value_2
11  file3  value_89
12  file3   value_2
```